# Acceptance event lost in the void

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, timestamps

I just stumbled over [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/65638/152859) which appears to be accepted:

> [image]

When trying to view when it was accepted, it's stuck for all eternity in "loading when this answer was accepted..." for the simple reason the [page it requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/65638/accepted-answer-date) returns 404. (literally)

There is no accept event in the [question timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/65636/timeline) as well.

At first I thought it's because the question author got deleted but checking [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144403/152859) with deleted OP who accepted [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/144406/152859) proved me wrong. ([link to request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/144406/accepted-answer-date))

I also tried looking at [Jeff reputation tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=reputation&sort=time&page=34) around the relevant date but there are only upvotes.

So, what went wrong here?

Comment: The quick answer is that there is no history record for the accept (checked the DB). The real question is why...

Comment: Back then Jeff was desperate for Meta rep @Oded? Add to that the full access and.... /tinfoil-hat.

Comment: No idea how to tag this now...

Comment: @Oded I'll tag this as [status-zombified](http://www.dbcovers.com/imagenes/backdrops/thumbs/resident_evil_ultratumba_2010//resident_evil_ultratumba_2010_3.jpg)!

Comment: [status-reproduced]: "something's wrong but we have no idea what" tag, [according to animuson](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177383/animated-profile-picture-on-mobile-site#comment533687_177383)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Old bug.

Accept votes used to be deleted with the question owner - by mistake. Looks like this is one of the answers caught by that bug.

I have searched but cannot find the bug report (though it may have not been reported...).

Comment: Can you restore the data somehow? If not, can you unaccept the answer?

Comment: I think this is essentially [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8621/incorrect-time-in-accepted-answer-tooltip), except that the implementation has changed slightly since then.

Comment: @TimStone - Looks like it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - That data is lost for eternity. I don't know about unaccepting the answer, just for this.

Comment: @Oded oh well, guess we can live with that. [meta-tag:status-norepro] then?

Comment: Is there anything you don't know @TimStone?

Comment: @Bart I have this persistent cough that I and my doctor can't figure out the source of, does that count?